# Javascript alert showing site url. How can i remove site url from top of javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, url, alert

javascript alert box showing url + msg. i have not passed any thing but it shows url on the top of alert box. how can i remove this url ? The url is showing when my site is redirected from another site.

Means redirect from abc.com to xyz.com and alert box showing xyz.com + msg ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can i remove site url from top of javascript alert?

You can't. The browser adds that so that the user knows that the message isn't from the browser itself.

The only thing you can do is stop using `alert` entirely, and instead use modern techniques for overlaying an element on top of the page. You can write this yourself, or use any of the many "lightbox" libraries out there. Note that doing so changes how you code things a bit, because while `alert` (and `confirm` and `prompt`) bring execution of scripts on the page to a screeching halt while they're on-screen, you can't do that in your own code, so you have to structure your code to continue when it receives the event that the user dismissed the box. Usually the library will give you a callback you can use for that, so for instance this `alert` code:

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    alert("Foo!");
    if (x != 42) {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

becomes

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    someNiftyLightboxThingy("Foo!", function() {
        if (x != 42) {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    });
}
```

Not hard, you just have to get used to it.

You don't *have* to use a library for this, but doing so lets you not worry about edge cases and may offer you more features. Here's a fairly bare-bones example:

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='btnPopup' value='Click for Pop-Up'>
```

CSS:

```
iframe.shim {
  width:            100%;
  height:           100%;
  position:         absolute;
  left:             0px;
  top:              0px;
  z-index:          100;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity:          0.5;                 /* Standard */
  filter:           alpha(opacity = 50); /* For IE */
}
div.overlay {
  z-index:          101;
  border:           1px solid black;
  background-color: #ecc;
  position:         absolute;
  left:             100px;
  top:              100px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function doVerySimplePopup(text, callback) {
  var shim, div, parent = document.body;

  shim = document.createElement('iframe');
  shim.className = 'shim';
  parent.appendChild(shim);

  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'overlay';
  div.innerHTML = text;
  parent.appendChild(div);
  div.onclick = function() {
    parent.removeChild(div);
    parent.removeChild(shim);
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      try { callback(); } catch (e) { }
    }
  };
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ocobu4/6)

Obviously you'd want to tart that up a bit, and again, this is a bare-bones example, not a complete solution.

Comment: @Sumit: Thanks. In what way, and in what browser? You click the "Click for popup" button and it puts in the overlay (you'll notice things get a bit dimmer, and you can't click the button again) with the message on top of it. Then you click the message and it disappears, and writes a message saying you've done that (to show how the callback works). Works fine here on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. I fired up a VM with IE6 and it worked except for the shim, probably something needed in the CSS (as I say, just an example, not perfect :-) ).

Answer (score 1):

@T.J. Crowder's answer is correct under normal circumstances. Although not completely. There are ways to bypass this, and get what you want in the end;

Was testing it out on http://htmledit.squarefree.com, basically just type in the text box:

```
<script>alert('whatever');</script>
```

And the output is an alert box without the URL.
Seems the work with most online html editors...

This is simplified;

```
<iframe id="myIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write('<script>alert("hello world");<\/script>');
ifrm.document.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Still popus up with "an embedded page on this page says..." in my Chrome browser