# hiding window.location URL

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the JavaScript thing. I have this script, all I need is to hide the url because it shows up in the message. if you look at window.location, you see the url that i want to hide in the prompt message, then the user will be redirected to that url.

```
<script>
  function confirmation() {
  var answer = confirm("Are You sure You want to cancel?")
  if (answer){
  alert("No information saved!")
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
    else{
    alert("You may hit save to submit information")
    setTimeout('confirmation()',10000);
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: URL doesn't show up in the alert box for me - firefox 8.0.1

Comment: You're right but shows up for google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript wont let you do that.

You can use the `jQuery` custom dialog box.
Check the example [here](http://www.webappers.com/2011/02/03/how-to-create-jquery-custom-confirm-dialog-replacement/)

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are redirecting to should not appear in the prompt message.

The URL of the page you are on *should*. This is an anti-phishing feature that makes sure users are informed where a message comes from so that webpages have a harder time making system dialogs that trick users into giving information to the wrong sites.

There is no way for an author of a page to disable this feature (it would be a pretty useless security measure if they could!).

Comment: so there's no other way? I was trying to create cancel button for a web form. is there a way to redirect a user to my index.php without having them to see My Url. This an android mobile web-based form. I managed to hide the address bar in my application. so, I don't want the users to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't change the title of `alert` or `confirm` because of security. You can use custom JavaScript dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to bypass the url showing on the popup alert;

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857492/2751668